# Click a random row in a table cypress

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I have a page in my app that shows outstanding defects for a user. I want a cypress to click on one of the rows, this takes you to a detail page.

I am able to select the table rows using

```
cy.get('[data-cy=faultsTable] tr').then(($tr)=>{

})
```

this correctly gets me 4 elements as expected. But I can't work out how to randomly choose one of them, as the .then wants to execute on each in turn.

I want to

a) get the defect id from 
b) click the row.

Any suggestions will be gratefully received

Answer (score 1):

There might be a better approach to this problem, but below is from my thought. If the number of `defect Id` records are less and are static, I mean from the table, you could probably pass those defect id into an array and return the `defect id` randomly.

**Option:1**
I have got a `sample.js` file in the `/support` folder where I have added the `randomDefectId` function.

```
module.exports ={
    randomDefectId: function(){
        var defect= ['10756', '10780', '19001', '21007', '25001', '27001'];
        var item = defect[Math.floor(Math.random()*defect.length)];
        return item;
    }

}
```

Then I have import them into my test spec

```
var rand = require('../../support/sample.js');
```

Below is my test where I am receiving the `rand.randomDefectId()` into a `const` `ranNumber`

```
 describe('Get the defect id', function(){
    it('Check whether the defect id', function(){
         const ranNumber = rand.getRandomNumber(); 
         cy.visit('/');         
         console.log("Some number:"+ranNumber );
          cy.get('#tableID>tbody>tr>td').contains(ranNumber).click()
          // rest of the test step continues here...

        })
    })
```

**Option:2**
But if there are a large list of `defect id` inside the table, then you need a dynamic way to get the defect id, I haven't tried the below script, but you could give a try..

```
randomDefectId: function(){
        let table = undefined;
        Cypress.$("#tableID>tbody>tr").each(function() {           
          var newArr = Cypress.$(this).find("td:last-child").html();          
          table = newArr;  
        });        
        return table;
    }
```

If there is better way of achieving this, I would like to know and share

Comment: What is the best practice to name 'sample.js' if I am creating a function to randomise something?

Comment: May be name `helperFunction.js` or `commonFunction.js ` something you like..